# I would like to know how to calculate Matrix

Tags: matrices

$\begin{pmatrix} 
x & y+2 \\
5z & 9k 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 8 \\
3 & 9 
\end{pmatrix}$

This is calculation of Matrix. $x= \frac{1}{3}, y=y+\frac{1}{4}, z= \frac{5}{3z}, k=k$

is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see "https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference"

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean. It seems like you have some kind transformation in the beginning. $x$ gets the value $\frac{1}{3}$, $y$ grows by $\frac{1}{4}$ etc. What does this have to do with a matrix? And what's the equation in the end?

Comment: thanks for the comments. just found that the question was changed to a different one after i posted here. what i meant is (x, y+1, 2z and 5k) must be in the left side and the size is 2,2. and this equation = (2, 8, 3, 9) for example and the size is 2, 2

Comment: Yet I am unable to understand your question. Do one thing, click a picture of your question and upload here.

Comment: just uploaded the link can u pls help me

Comment: According to your picture uploaded by you, i.e., $\begin{pmatrix} 
x & y+2 \\
5z & 9k 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 8 \\
3 & 9 
\end{pmatrix}$, we can tell that $x=2$, $y=6, z=\frac{3}{5}, k=1$

Comment: understand . thanks for your quick reply

Answer (score 1):

It is not obvious what you want or how you obtained you values for $x$, $y$, etc.

My understanding is that you want to calculated the variables values according to equality of the two matrices. If this is incorrect, let me know.

When two matrices $A$, $B$ are equal you can compare corresponding elements. So, $a_{ij}$=$b_{ij}$.

In you case:

$$x=2$$
$$y+2=8  \Rightarrow\ y=6$$
$$5z=3  \Rightarrow\ z=\frac{3}{5}$$
$$9k=9  \Rightarrow\ k=1$$